# ASP.NET identity core vs. self hosted authentication vs. third party authentication provider

Tags: authentication, asp.net-identity, keycloak

I'm building an ASP.NET API with Flutter frontend.
I want to authenticate a user, authorize and store user information like date of birth.

As far as I've learned there are 3 options:

1. Use ASP.NET core identity with EF and SQL Server. All data including credentials, roles, user information is stored locally and I can also test locally with Docker
2. Use a self hosted authentication like Keycloak or Duende. Credentials and (maybe even) roles are stored in such a self hosted provider, user information is stored in a local database
3. Third party provider like Auth0, Azure B2C to name a few. Credentials are stored on their platform, roles and user information locally.

The questions I didn't find satisfying answers for:
A) Storing ANY user information like personal information as well as credentials: Is this reasonable? Is there another way as providers like Auth0 don't offer such storage possibilities?
B) Hosting a provider like Keycloak in a docker container: Is this really secure? Point is: I'm not a keycloak developer nor very advanced dev ops. I could put the docker containers on Azure but still the question remains: Can I handle security of Keycloak or Duende on my own?
C) Is storing information locally (or on a docker container in the cloud) with ASP.NET core identity and a SQL Server more for hobbyists but as I wanna offer an ecommerce platform I should...  yeah, what shall I do?

Thanks for any into the right direction.

Boris

I've studied ASP.NET core identity with MVC and Blazor, Keycloak with an ASP.NET core API and took a detailed look at Auth0, Azure B2C

Answer (score -1):

I would recommand keycloak. 
"ASP.NET core identity" is basically cookie based. It's not that secure and has many disadvantage.  https://developer.okta.com/blog/2022/02/08/cookies-vs-tokens. Especially when you want some function like SSO (single-sign on), this way cannot acheive.
Self-hosted authentication and 3rd party provider are using same Oauth flows. 3rd-party provider has better documentation and support but it is not free. When doing commerce you would better save the costs for these. Learning to implement KeyCloak takes time, but it is still a mature solution.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion.
What do u mean by „save costs for these“?
Invest for an external provider like Auth0 or „save the money and invest time into keycloak“

Comment: @Boris I mean save the money

Comment: The link provided in this answer to argue that cookies are not secure actually advocates for cookies on a website: "You should use cookies when you need to keep track of user interactions, such as with an e-commerce application or website. You can use tokens when building API services or implementing distributed systems."

Additionally, this answer could be improved by comparing the various options asked in the question, and giving recommendations for when each would be appropriate.